# CUDA 7.5 with visual studio 2013 and open cv 3.0.0 .errors while building a cuda code

Tags: c++, gpu

> Cannot open include file: opencv2/cudafilters.hpp: No such file or directory

I am getting this error while trying to build the following code 
`ConsoleApplication71.cpp`: Defines the entry point for the console application.

```
#include "stdafx.h"


#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudafilters.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::cuda;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
cv::cuda::setDevice(0);
// -------------------------------
// 
// -------------------------------
Mat img = imread("test.png", 0);
int erosionDilation_size = 5;
Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(2 * erosionDilation_size + 1, 2 * erosionDilation_size + 1));

cuda::GpuMat d_element(element);
cuda::GpuMat d_img(img);

Ptr<cuda::Filter> dilateFilter = cuda::createMorphologyFilter(MORPH_DILATE, d_img.type(), element);
dilateFilter->apply(d_img, d_img);


d_img.download(img);

d_img.release();
d_element.release();

imshow("test", img);
waitKey();
}
```

Comment: This is not an information security issue but simply a problem compiling a 3rd party program. I recommend to move it to superuser.com.

Comment: Clearly off topic , but to help you have `cudaimgproc.hpp` file missing it must be into your opencv /bin directory